# Wcf Service Accessing database Access for all

Tags: database, entity-framework, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a situation where i am using a mvc client and there is a web reference of wcf service, in wcf service i am using Entity framework and using some database.

Now i want to use this mvc solution for multiple user for training purpose but it won't allow because they won't have the database access of the server.

Is there any way by which they can use the solution and access the database via service methods ?

It is fine if i need to set my crediantials somewhere to make it public ?

Please suggest !!

Thanks,
Ankit

Answer (score 0):

For inserting data into the database you need to write the following code in the IService.cs file which contains the two sections:

```
OperationContract
DataContract
```

The OperationContract section is used to add service operations and DataContract is used to add types to service operations.

Here I am creating a function in the OperationContract section of the IEmployeeService.cs file:

```
public interface IEmployeeService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string InsertDate(EmployeeInfo empInfo);
}
```

Now I am going to add Service operation in data contract section..

```
public class EmployeeInfo 
{

    int ID=0;
    string Employeename = "";
    string EmpID = "";
    string EmailID = ""; 

    [DataMember]
    public string ID
    {
        get { return ID; }
        set { ID= value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Employeename 
    {
        get { return Employeename ; }
        set { Employeename = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Country
    {
        get { return country; }
        set { country = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string EmailID 
    {
        get { return EmailID ; }
        set { EmailID = value; }
    }
}
```

Now use the following code..

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Runtime.Serialization;
 using System.ServiceModel;
 using System.ServiceModel.Web;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.Data; 

 namespace WCFServiceAcceessDataBase
 {
   public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
   {
     public string InsertDate(EmployeeInfo employeeInfo )
     {
        string Message;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Jom;User ID=sa;Password=333");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblEmployee(ID,Employeename ,EmpID,EmailID) values(@ID,@Employeename ,@EmpID,@EmailID)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", employeeInfo.ID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employeename ", employeeInfo.Employeename);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", employeeInfo.EmpID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailID", employeeInfo.EmailID);
        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (result == 1)
        {
            Message = employeeInfo.Employeename + " Information Saved";
        }
        else
        {
            Message = employeeInfo.Employeename + " Information not Saved ";
        }
        con.Close();
        return Message;
     }
   }
 }
```

I think this may help you

Thank you

Jom George